# Odd result when displaying MySQL result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a web application that uses a MySQL database. After a query, I want to echo the result into a table.

PHP Code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo "<table>";
foreach($rows as $item) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$item['column1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['column2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['column3']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The result is just a bunch of random characters in a table.
What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` retrieves only _one_ row. Your `foreach` then iterates over that row's columns and the array indexes (if you are actually using numeric array indexes, since column1, column2, column3 don't sound real) are  retrieving string character indexes.

Comment: Typically, you would call `mysqli_fetch_array()` in a `while` loop  `while ($item = $mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {...}` There are [many examples in the official documentation](http://us1.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski How do I get all of the rows returned?

Comment: Use a while loop like my previous comment, but without the errant $ I left on the function name. Remove the foreach entirely and use only the while loop.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Using the while loop worked, but I was wondering whether there was a method in which a foreach loop worked... Maybe in in the old mysql functions?

Comment: @SanBergam In PHP 5.4+, [a `mysqli_result` object](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) (which is what `mysqli_query()` returns) implements the `Traversable` interface. That means if you have PHP 5.4, you can directly do `foreach ($query as $row) {...}` with no explicit `mysqli_fetch_array()` calls.

Comment: [There's also `mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get all rows in one array which you can `foreach`, but that method only works with the mysqlnd driver, not available on all systems.  Consequently `mysqli_fetch_all()` isn't used as often as an example since it won't work everywhere. The traversable method is great if you have >=PHP 5.4 but quite a lot of people still use 5.3.

Answer (score -1):

The semicolon `;` seems to be missing from the three 'echo' lines when you print the column data..

Try this:

```
echo "<td>".$item['column1']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$item['column2']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$item['column3']."</td>";
```

Comment: While you are correct, this doesn't answer the original question. Please update your answer to include an answer or explanation of the problem described.

Comment: Since it was impossible to guess what the OP had in its tables I could only begin with what was provided.. and that was code with some errors. I informed the OP of the errors but have no way of checking whether my suggestion would fix his problem. Feel free to convert my answer to a comment instead.

Comment: Michael proposed a solution that answers the question in the comments. Your answer, while valid in it's own context, doesn't answer the question being asked as the random characters still display.

Comment: @captcha Your observation is correct, though my actual code doesn't have that problem, but rather, when I was quickly typing up a more brief version of it. I edited my post with the corrections.